# Neural network not training, parameters.grad is None

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, minimization

I implemented a simple NN and a custom objective function for a minimization problem. Everything seems to be working fine, except for the fact that the model does not seem to learn.

I checked if list(network.parameters())[0].grad was None, and indeed this seems to be the problem. Based on previously asked questions, the problem seems to be the detachment of the graph, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's the link to the code that you can run on colab: [Colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wjamdASF-flkfDVL6-5HoFuAtXzi2uek?usp=sharing)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part seems problematic in your code.

```
  output_grad, _ = torch.autograd.grad(q, (x,y))
  output_grad.requires_grad_()
```

Your loss depends on `output_grad` and so when you do `loss.backward()` are trying to compute the gradient of parameters w.r.t to `output_grad`.

You cannot compute the gradient of `output_grad` since `create_graph` is `False` by default. And so `output_grad` is implicitly detached from the rest of the graph. To fix this, just pass `create_graph=True` in the `autograd.grad`. You do not need to set `requires_grad` either for output_grad, i.e., the second line is not needed.

Comment: If I set create_graph=True I get the error:

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

I feel like I am missing something dumb here. The problem is that I need to calculate the gradient in the objective function, perhaps I need to compute it in another way.

Comment: I am still trying to reason the issue, but it seems that your input tensor `configuration` is a result of various operations such as index lookup and `.view()` and that may be causing the issue regarding backpropagating twice. I don't think those operations need to part of your computation graph, so If you would detach the inputs as below ```configuration = configuration.detach()
    configuration.requires_grad_()``` before inputting the network that should fix your problem.